# cocos2d-js scale sprite not working

Tags: cocos2d-js

I am trying to scale a cocos2d sprite with

```
this.mask.setScaleY(percent/100);
```

This happens within an interval.

Unfortunately the sprite vanishes after the first time the `setScaleY` function is called.

Do I need to re-render it manually?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You use the function correctlly, most probably on the second iteration your sprite vanishes because the percent/100 value is too low. Add some console.log statements before re-scaling/check it out in the debugger - I'm pretty sure it's the value

Comment: Hello and thanks. It was a problem with the mask being inside ClippingNode ...